# how to make graphite support metrics with non-ascii characters

Tags: graphite

I sent metrics with non-ascii characters into graphite, then the file was created successfully, but I can't query it.

1. the file in file system was created: whisper_root/test/测试/recs.wsp
2. but the metrics can't be shown in the graphite tree view: [this is the graphite tree snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzEZs.png)
3. when I put the query url (http://192.168.16.35:8085/metrics/find/?_dc=1488781861984&query=test.%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95.*&format=treejson&path=test.%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95&node=test.%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95) in the browser, I get this response: "Missing required parameter 'query'"

HOW can I get the graphite working with metrics with non-ascii characters? thanks.